# register_term_meta not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, term-meta

I have a simple code snippet, and seems like I am missing something obvious.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_term_meta_setup');
function custom_term_meta_setup() {
    register_term_meta( 'procedures', 'source_post_id', array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'description' => '',
        'single' => true
    ) );
}
```

I tried to hook this to some actions which are executed a bit later, such as `wp_meta`, but had no luck.

Tried it in both Docker local env, and in a regular local (MAMP) WP installation, had no luck.

Tried to do the same thing with `register_meta`, unsuccessful.

Tried with `sting` type, no luck.

PS:
To see the results, I am echoing the "procedures" term I expect to get this meta field:

```
$terms = get_term( 49 );
echo "<pre>" . var_export( $terms, true ) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am echoing the "procedures" term I expect to get this meta field

[`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) returns a [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) object which *by default* does not include any metadata, even for registered meta keys.

So registering a meta key does *not* automatically add it to the term object, but registering a meta key has 2 main benefits:

1. You can set a default value for the meta, which is returned when you call [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) or [`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/), see the `default` argument [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/#parameters).
2. You can make the meta be accessible via the REST API, via the `show_in_rest` argument (see the same link above).

So for example, if you set `default` to 1234 and `show_in_rest` to `true`, then a request for a taxonomy's collection in the REST API (e.g. at `/wp-json/wp/v2/procedures`) would contain a `"meta":{"source_post_id":1234}` in the JSON response, for terms without that meta.